# Multiple Instances of 1 Program

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, file-management, sandbox, sandboxie

The project at hand that I am having issues with is that I need to run a set of program models on one computer. Each model has different file configurations, but in the C:\ drive the folders are named the same as the program looks for these when starting. On top of that there is a security dongle. I have tried running them sandboxed w/Sandboxie, it works this way but to make it usable I would have to go and change the directories in the code... witch are a lot of areas in the code. The other option that I tried was VirtualBox, this would work excellent, but the issue with this is that it doesn't detect the security dongle (LPT). What other options do I have, other than changing up the code. Maybe a new setup or some other utility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that documentation is sparse, but VirtualBox does have LPT support as of 4.2.

From the [Commands Overview](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp55423424)

> `--lptmode<1-N> <Device>` Specifies the Device Name of the parallel port that the Parallel Port feature will be using. Use this before `--lpt`.
>   This feature is host operating system specific.
>
> `--lpt<1-N> <I/O base> <IRQ>` Specifies the I/O address of the parallel port and the IRQ number that the Parallel Port feature will be using.
>   Use this after `--lptmod`. I/O base address and IRQ are the values that
>   guest sees i.e. the values avalable under guest Device Manager.

This also looks useful:

- [Enabling and Configuring Parallel (LPTx) Ports](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=54187)